# Android:How to let the HEAP SIZE lower?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

The question is:
When my app first start,it will show the guest pages which using some big pictures(I can't let the pictures smaller). These pictures spend more than 10M memory.So at that time the heap size is more than 20M. It doesn't matter at that time.
Then my app use a **long-time running service** and the service use about 10M memory.But when users look at the "Running Apps" in the Settings, they will see my app use 20M memory but not 10M! This is because **my heap size is always 20M! How could I let the heap size lower???**
P.S.I'm a Chinese so my English is poor,I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: I think your heap size will shrink again if you make sure the Garbage Collector can do its work and don't hold onto items such as pictures that are not needed anymore. But in general, i wouldn't worry to much about the heap size as long as you are sure not to get an out of memory exception and have a decent reason to use a big heap, such as showing a lot of big pictures.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I look at the DDMS's "heap". The heap size is 20M,but the Allocated size is only 10M.It shows that the pictures has been destroyed.Then I cause GC for more than 10 times,and the heap size still not shrink.And, I'm worried about the heap size, because there are many little-memory phone in China (such as 512M on Android 4.0). The users will be angry when they see my program use 20M.On the other hand,some other programs which is my competitor just use 4.0M !!! Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you put your UI and background service in separate processes, you shouldn't have this problem. Of course, moving to a multi-process architecture is very complicated, but I've tried it and found that it works.